# Best way to return a callback from a react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-hooks

I want to make a custom hook that reacts to the click event of some element and do some state update:

```js
function useCustom() {
  // a sample state within the hook
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  // the callback I'm talking about
  const onClick = event => {
    console.log(`Hey! counter is ${counter}`);
    setCounter(val=>val+1);
  }

  // returning the callback to be used in the component
  return {onClick};
}
```

Now the component that uses this hook

```js
function MyComp(props) {
  const cbs = useCustom();

  // component onclick handler
  const onClick = event => cbs.onClick(event);

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button>
}
```

There are some issues with this approach. First off,the callabck function onClick within the hook is somehow connected to the very first closure of this hook, meaning that the value of counter in it is always 0 (it keeps logging "Hey! counter is 0" on each click). Well, to solve this problem I need to use useRef ... I know how to do that but my main concern here is that this callback somehow is connected to the early (and outdated) closure of the hook, and so it keeps this closure (and all its variables) alive (not be garbage-collected) and thus it is a kind of memory leak (?? am I making a mistake here) - so is it in general a good practice to return a callback like this from a hook???

An altenative solution which seems more react-ish, would be to use a state variable instead of the callback within the hook and return the set state function of that state:

```js
function useCustom() {
  // a sample state within the hook
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  // state to hold the last click event
  const [clickEvent, setClickEvent] = useState(null);

  // replacing the callback with an effect callback
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Hey! counter is ${counter}`);
    setCounter(val=>val+1);
  }, [clickEvent]);

  // returning the set state function instead of callback
  return {setClickEvent};
}
```

And then in the component:

```js
function MyComp(props) {
  const cbs = useCustom();

  // component onclick handler
  const onClick = event => cbs.setClickEvent(event);

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button>
}
```

Note that the downside of this, we will have two rendering (i.e. execution) of the hook upon click (one because of setClickEvent and next for setCounter within the effect for clickEvent ...). This could be its tradeoff compare to the callback approach.

So which one wins? callback method or setState method, or ... ??

Comment: why wouldnt you pass the counter and update function as variables to the custom hook?

Comment: @Tobi The counter in the above example is just for illustration. The actual code has much much more states and logic inside the hook ... you mean we should not use state inside the hook?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous. You can see in this documentation by React:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-valuejs
- https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous

You can log the value by adding a `useEffect` to `counter` which will trigger when the counter changes:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Hey! counter is ${counter}`); // <= log when counter changes
  }, [counter]);
```

Working example:

```js
function useCustom() {
  // a sample state within the hook
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  // the callback I'm talking about
  const onClick = (event) => {
    setCounter((val) => val + 1);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Hey! counter is ${counter}`);
  }, [counter]);

  // returning the callback to be used in the component
  return { onClick };
}
function App() {
  const cbs = useCustom();
  // component onclick handler
  const onClick = (event) => cbs.onClick(event);

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I guess you did not read the question at all

Comment: `(it keeps logging "Hey! counter is 0" on each click)` This is mentioned in your question.

Comment: and continuing: "... Well, to solve this problem I need to use useRef ... I know how to do that but **my main concern here is** ... [the main question is asked here] "

Comment: What do you mean by `this callback somehow is connected to the early (and outdated) closure of the hook`? What issue did you observe with this?

Comment: I don't see any memory issues related to the implementation above. And the custom hook in the example above is so trivial, that I'd rather put the effects and state in the component itself, viz essentially the same code.